# Get refunded items (only simple products: qty and price) programmtically

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo

I have wrote a script to try to get the refunded items qty and price

```
foreach($credit_memos as $credit_memo) {

    $items = $credit_memo->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo $item->getSku()." X ".$item->getQty()."<br>";
    }

}
```

but it print out also the configurable item

test2 X 1.0000
mtk005 X 1.0000
mtk005 X 1.0000
wbk004 X 99.0000
wbk004 X 1.0000

Here are my questions
1) how can i get refunded amount of each item?
2) how can i remove the configurable line?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
foreach($credit_memos as $credit_memo) {

    $items = $credit_memo->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo $item->getSku()." X ".$item->getQty()."<br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: getAllVisibleItems display nothing, i had tried before